# R GLM get probability density for a GLM model

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, density-function, glmm

I train a GLM via

```
model<- glm(formula=y \sim x_1+x_2,family=Gamma
(link=log),data=...)
```

I now would like to get the probability density function of $f_{\theta(x_1,x_2)}(y)$ for pairs of feature $(x_1,x_2)$ and output $y$. Is there any way to get it?